# Very lightweight installation of MySQL (without commercial embedded mode license)

Tags: mysql, delphi, desktop-application

I would like to use MySQL database as local temporary database in desktop application, is there installation mode that does support such use case? E.g. user is required to copy only some dll's and maybe some configuration or log files and nothing more (no installation directory in Program Files, no opening ports).

I know that MySQL provides commercial embedded mode (I guess - MySQL functionality can be compiled into the final executable), but maybe there is more options which do not require such commercial license? E.g. maybe it is not needed for using dll's only.

C++ Builder or Delphi are possible languages for mentioned desktop application.

Comment: Any particular reason for MySQL and not SQLite or other embeddable database?

Comment: Yes, there is reason fot not using SQLite: the type of it's fields (that are listed in select clause) is evaluated only in runtime and can be different depending on the query parameters. This is especaily bad for null values.

Comment: Firebird has mandatory use of transactions, while optimized still this has some weight. That is why MySQL seems to be better in this case.

Answer (score 2):

MySQL is available in an embedded DLL or SO file from MySQL under a GPL licence, like most other MySQL software. You can use and distribute it under the terms of the GPL at no cost, which in the case of an embedded component requires that your own software is GPL (or GPL-compatible). The filename is `libmysql.dll` (or `.so`) and packaged with MySQL installers or distributions, such as those that come from http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql/.

Baron Schwartz has a [useful article](http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2009/02/17/when-are-you-required-to-have-a-commercial-mysql-license/) summarizing the issues, assuming you're talking about using the GPL (Community Edition) version of MySQL embedded, and not a commercial release. He says:

> You need a commercial license if you want to embed MySQL within your non-Free program. Note  that embed is not the same as “make a connection to.”

Of course, he also says he's not a lawyer (nor am I), so you should bear that in mind when considering using GPL software (or any other licence) in your application.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there is a free "embedded" version. You may want to look at other options such as SQLite etc.

Comment: SQLLite is out of question (type issues). Java has Cloydscape/Apache Derby database, but it's Java.

Comment: My db of choice for this kind of thing is Firebird.   Definitely worth a look.